# using mongoose.connect when uploading my website to heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose, npm

I have installed node.js npm mongodb and mongoose to create a website with a database. Locally, I use mongoose.connect(mongodb://localhost/test) and has no issue. Everything is working fine.

However when I try to host this site in heroku I got the error saying 'couldn't connect to localhost'. I understand that I need to change the mongodb uri. I have uploaded my project files to github.

I am not sure how the uri need to be changed. Really appreciate your support.

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=mongodb+connect+heroku

Comment: According to all of the readings I have done, in order to use mongodb I require the use of mongolab or a different add-on. Is that the only way this is doable?

Comment: MongoDB is a seperate service in itself and not part of your application. You need to connect to it somewhere, and it will not launch on localhost. Heroku deploments are just for the application. You need another host to run a MongoDB instance on.

Comment: Can you please give me any suggestions as to where I could host my MongoDB database?

Answer (score 1):

Heroku don't allow you to use a MongoDB inside your app, you'll need to use something like MongoLab or other heroku addon to do this job.

Answer (score 1):

I got your point. To use your Mongolab created database in your application,
replace your mongouri that connects to localhost with the below code snippet.
I have recently created a separate MongoLab account, created my database in it and then picked up the URI to connect to it. You can happily use this code as is and host your application in Heroku. It wont stop you. All the best.
[I have written an article on hosting app to Heroku step-by-step on blog.](http://eshwartechtalks.blogspot.in/2015/08/step-by-step-installation-of-nodejs.html)

```
mongoose = require('mongoose');
var mongouri = 'mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@[mongolabuniquevalue]/[your-db-name]';
mongoose.connect(mongoUri);

//<dbuser> is created using the Users tab in the dashboard  along with a password that you set for <dbpassword>
```

Look at the below image from my dashboard. Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I am trying to not use Mongolab and try to host the database in Amazon EC2.

Comment: Hi Anne, if you have found the post as an answer can you mark it as answer?